# PyCUDA inconsistent results on the same platform

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I am implementing a password cracker for college work using `PyCUDA`. Everything seems to be working correctly except the implementation of the NTLM algorithm on CUDA.

To test it out, I created a small module that launches a kernel with only 1 thread, hashes a value and returns it for comparison with the hash obtained on the CPU. Here is the code below:

```py
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy
from passlib.hash import nthash

mod = SourceModule(
"""
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INIT_A 0x67452301
#define INIT_B 0xefcdab89
#define INIT_C 0x98badcfe
#define INIT_D 0x10325476

#define SQRT_2 0x5a827999
#define SQRT_3 0x6ed9eba1

__device__ void NTLM(char *, int, char*);

//__device__ char hex_format[33];
__device__ __constant__ char itoa16[17] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

__global__ void NTBruteforce(char *hex_format){   
    int i;

    char test[4] = {'t', 'h', 'e', 'n'};

    NTLM(test, 4, hex_format);      

}
__device__ void NTLM(char *key, int key_length, char *hex_format) {
    unsigned int nt_buffer[16];
    unsigned int output[4];

    //Globals for rounds
    unsigned int a = INIT_A;
    unsigned int b = INIT_B;
    unsigned int c = INIT_C;
    unsigned int d = INIT_D;

    // Prepare the string for hash calculation

    int i;
    int length = key_length;
    //memset(nt_buffer, 0, 4);
    for (i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
        nt_buffer[i] = key[2 * i] | (key[2 * i + 1] << 16);

    //padding
    if (length % 2 == 1)
        nt_buffer[i] = key[length - 1] | 0x800000;
    else
        nt_buffer[i] = 0x80;
    //put the length

    nt_buffer[14] = length << 4;

    // NTLM hash calculation

    /* Round 1 */
    a += (d ^ (b & (c ^ d))) + nt_buffer[0];
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ (a & (b ^ c))) + nt_buffer[1];
    d = (d << 7) | (d >> 25);
    c += (b ^ (d & (a ^ b))) + nt_buffer[2];
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ (c & (d ^ a))) + nt_buffer[3];
    b = (b << 19) | (b >> 13);

    a += (d ^ (b & (c ^ d))) + nt_buffer[4];
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ (a & (b ^ c))) + nt_buffer[5];
    d = (d << 7) | (d >> 25);
    c += (b ^ (d & (a ^ b))) + nt_buffer[6];
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ (c & (d ^ a))) + nt_buffer[7];
    b = (b << 19) | (b >> 13);

    a += (d ^ (b & (c ^ d))) + nt_buffer[8];
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ (a & (b ^ c))) + nt_buffer[9];
    d = (d << 7) | (d >> 25);
    c += (b ^ (d & (a ^ b))) + nt_buffer[10];
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ (c & (d ^ a))) + nt_buffer[11];
    b = (b << 19) | (b >> 13);

    a += (d ^ (b & (c ^ d))) + nt_buffer[12];
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ (a & (b ^ c))) + nt_buffer[13];
    d = (d << 7) | (d >> 25);
    c += (b ^ (d & (a ^ b))) + nt_buffer[14];
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ (c & (d ^ a))) + nt_buffer[15];
    b = (b << 19) | (b >> 13);

    /* Round 2 */
    a += ((b & (c | d)) | (c & d)) + nt_buffer[0] + SQRT_2;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += ((a & (b | c)) | (b & c)) + nt_buffer[4] + SQRT_2;
    d = (d << 5) | (d >> 27);
    c += ((d & (a | b)) | (a & b)) + nt_buffer[8] + SQRT_2;
    c = (c << 9) | (c >> 23);
    b += ((c & (d | a)) | (d & a)) + nt_buffer[12] + SQRT_2;
    b = (b << 13) | (b >> 19);

    a += ((b & (c | d)) | (c & d)) + nt_buffer[1] + SQRT_2;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += ((a & (b | c)) | (b & c)) + nt_buffer[5] + SQRT_2;
    d = (d << 5) | (d >> 27);
    c += ((d & (a | b)) | (a & b)) + nt_buffer[9] + SQRT_2;
    c = (c << 9) | (c >> 23);
    b += ((c & (d | a)) | (d & a)) + nt_buffer[13] + SQRT_2;
    b = (b << 13) | (b >> 19);

    a += ((b & (c | d)) | (c & d)) + nt_buffer[2] + SQRT_2;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += ((a & (b | c)) | (b & c)) + nt_buffer[6] + SQRT_2;
    d = (d << 5) | (d >> 27);
    c += ((d & (a | b)) | (a & b)) + nt_buffer[10] + SQRT_2;
    c = (c << 9) | (c >> 23);
    b += ((c & (d | a)) | (d & a)) + nt_buffer[14] + SQRT_2;
    b = (b << 13) | (b >> 19);

    a += ((b & (c | d)) | (c & d)) + nt_buffer[3] + SQRT_2;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += ((a & (b | c)) | (b & c)) + nt_buffer[7] + SQRT_2;
    d = (d << 5) | (d >> 27);
    c += ((d & (a | b)) | (a & b)) + nt_buffer[11] + SQRT_2;
    c = (c << 9) | (c >> 23);
    b += ((c & (d | a)) | (d & a)) + nt_buffer[15] + SQRT_2;
    b = (b << 13) | (b >> 19);

    /* Round 3 */
    a += (d ^ c ^ b) + nt_buffer[0] + SQRT_3;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ b ^ a) + nt_buffer[8] + SQRT_3;
    d = (d << 9) | (d >> 23);
    c += (b ^ a ^ d) + nt_buffer[4] + SQRT_3;
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ d ^ c) + nt_buffer[12] + SQRT_3;
    b = (b << 15) | (b >> 17);

    a += (d ^ c ^ b) + nt_buffer[2] + SQRT_3;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ b ^ a) + nt_buffer[10] + SQRT_3;
    d = (d << 9) | (d >> 23);
    c += (b ^ a ^ d) + nt_buffer[6] + SQRT_3;
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ d ^ c) + nt_buffer[14] + SQRT_3;
    b = (b << 15) | (b >> 17);

    a += (d ^ c ^ b) + nt_buffer[1] + SQRT_3;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ b ^ a) + nt_buffer[9] + SQRT_3;
    d = (d << 9) | (d >> 23);
    c += (b ^ a ^ d) + nt_buffer[5] + SQRT_3;
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ d ^ c) + nt_buffer[13] + SQRT_3;
    b = (b << 15) | (b >> 17);

    a += (d ^ c ^ b) + nt_buffer[3] + SQRT_3;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ b ^ a) + nt_buffer[11] + SQRT_3;
    d = (d << 9) | (d >> 23);
    c += (b ^ a ^ d) + nt_buffer[7] + SQRT_3;
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ d ^ c) + nt_buffer[15] + SQRT_3;
    b = (b << 15) | (b >> 17);

    output[0] = a + 0x67452301;
    output[1] = b + 0xefcdab89;
    output[2] = c + 0x98badcfe;
    output[3] = d + 0x10325476;
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Convert the hash to hex (for being readable)
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            unsigned int n = output[i];
            //iterate the bytes of the integer
            for(; j<4; j++)
            {
                unsigned int convert = n % 256;
                hex_format[i * 8 + j * 2 + 1] = itoa16[convert % 16];
                convert = convert / 16;
                hex_format[i * 8 + j * 2 + 0] = itoa16[convert % 16];
                n = n / 256;
            }
        }       
} 
""")
expected = nthash.encrypt('then')
data = numpy.array(expected)
cleartext = numpy.zeros_like(data)
cleartext_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(data.nbytes)
func = mod.get_function('NTBruteforce')
func(cleartext_gpu, block=(1,1,1))
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(cleartext, cleartext_gpu)
print 'Expected: {}'.format(expected.upper())
print "GPU     : {}".format(cleartext.tostring())
```

The problem is that I get different results on consecutive runs. Sometimes I get the correct result a few times in a row, but the next time I run it (after 2-3 secs), the result is wrong. My output looks like this:

```py
Expected: 35B5C3F393D57F7836FF61514BCF1289
GPU     : 90ABFDFAA5F9F1F25DAF679A3FC1331F

Expected: 35B5C3F393D57F7836FF61514BCF1289
GPU     : 4A3F30740C38FC259867716DF887349B

Expected: 35B5C3F393D57F7836FF61514BCF1289
GPU     : 2CA784517A80BBE10437EE88CFDEC269

Expected: 35B5C3F393D57F7836FF61514BCF1289
GPU     : 35B5C3F393D57F7836FF61514BCF1289

Expected: 35B5C3F393D57F7836FF61514BCF1289
GPU     : 35B5C3F393D57F7836FF61514BCF1289

Expected: 35B5C3F393D57F7836FF61514BCF1289
GPU     : 8EA84AB098A6C8E37FFF1F6440127273
```

The above output is just an example of running the program a few times consecutively.
As you can see I get the correct result sometimes (and sometimes consecutively as well) but other times the result is wrong and I don't understand why.

I've tried re-installing the CUDA SDK (version 4.2.9) and rebooting my computer but the same thing happens.

Using Windows 7 64-bit, Geforce GT240

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `nt_buffer`. What you observed is a typical consequence of uninitialized variables: the junk in memory may vary from one run to the next, hence the inconsistent results. Simply changing the variable declaration line by:

```cpp
unsigned int nt_buffer[16] = { 0 };
```

should fix your issue (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/1043187) for information on C-style array initialization). Here is the complete (fix + error checking) CUDA/C++ code for those interested:

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INIT_A 0x67452301
#define INIT_B 0xefcdab89
#define INIT_C 0x98badcfe
#define INIT_D 0x10325476

#define SQRT_2 0x5a827999
#define SQRT_3 0x6ed9eba1

#define CUDA_CHECK_ERROR()  __cuda_check_errors(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL(err) __cuda_safe_call(err, __FILE__, __LINE__)

inline void __cuda_check_errors(const char *filename, const int line_number)
{
    cudaError err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if(err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CUDA error %i at %s:%i: %s\n",
               err, filename, line_number, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }
}

inline void __cuda_safe_call(cudaError err, const char *filename, const int line_number)
{
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CUDA error %i at %s:%i: %s\n",
               err, filename, line_number, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }
}

__device__ void NTLM(char *, int, char*);
__device__ __constant__ char itoa16[17] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

__global__ void NTBruteforce(char *hex_format){
    char test[4] = {'t', 'h', 'e', 'n'};
    NTLM(test, 4, hex_format);      
}

__device__ void NTLM(char *key, int key_length, char *hex_format) {
    unsigned int nt_buffer[16] = { 0 };
    unsigned int output[4] = { 0 };

    //Globals for rounds
    unsigned int a = INIT_A;
    unsigned int b = INIT_B;
    unsigned int c = INIT_C;
    unsigned int d = INIT_D;

    // Prepare the string for hash calculation
    int i;
    int length = key_length;

    for (i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
        nt_buffer[i] = key[2 * i] | (key[2 * i + 1] << 16);

    //padding
    if (length % 2 == 1)
        nt_buffer[i] = key[length - 1] | 0x800000;
    else
        nt_buffer[i] = 0x80;

    //put the length
    nt_buffer[14] = length << 4;

    // NTLM hash calculation

    /* Round 1 */
    a += (d ^ (b & (c ^ d))) + nt_buffer[0];
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ (a & (b ^ c))) + nt_buffer[1];
    d = (d << 7) | (d >> 25);
    c += (b ^ (d & (a ^ b))) + nt_buffer[2];
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ (c & (d ^ a))) + nt_buffer[3];
    b = (b << 19) | (b >> 13);

    a += (d ^ (b & (c ^ d))) + nt_buffer[4];
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ (a & (b ^ c))) + nt_buffer[5];
    d = (d << 7) | (d >> 25);
    c += (b ^ (d & (a ^ b))) + nt_buffer[6];
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ (c & (d ^ a))) + nt_buffer[7];
    b = (b << 19) | (b >> 13);

    a += (d ^ (b & (c ^ d))) + nt_buffer[8];
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ (a & (b ^ c))) + nt_buffer[9];
    d = (d << 7) | (d >> 25);
    c += (b ^ (d & (a ^ b))) + nt_buffer[10];
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ (c & (d ^ a))) + nt_buffer[11];
    b = (b << 19) | (b >> 13);

    a += (d ^ (b & (c ^ d))) + nt_buffer[12];
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ (a & (b ^ c))) + nt_buffer[13];
    d = (d << 7) | (d >> 25);
    c += (b ^ (d & (a ^ b))) + nt_buffer[14];
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ (c & (d ^ a))) + nt_buffer[15];
    b = (b << 19) | (b >> 13);

    /* Round 2 */
    a += ((b & (c | d)) | (c & d)) + nt_buffer[0] + SQRT_2;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += ((a & (b | c)) | (b & c)) + nt_buffer[4] + SQRT_2;
    d = (d << 5) | (d >> 27);
    c += ((d & (a | b)) | (a & b)) + nt_buffer[8] + SQRT_2;
    c = (c << 9) | (c >> 23);
    b += ((c & (d | a)) | (d & a)) + nt_buffer[12] + SQRT_2;
    b = (b << 13) | (b >> 19);

    a += ((b & (c | d)) | (c & d)) + nt_buffer[1] + SQRT_2;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += ((a & (b | c)) | (b & c)) + nt_buffer[5] + SQRT_2;
    d = (d << 5) | (d >> 27);
    c += ((d & (a | b)) | (a & b)) + nt_buffer[9] + SQRT_2;
    c = (c << 9) | (c >> 23);
    b += ((c & (d | a)) | (d & a)) + nt_buffer[13] + SQRT_2;
    b = (b << 13) | (b >> 19);

    a += ((b & (c | d)) | (c & d)) + nt_buffer[2] + SQRT_2;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += ((a & (b | c)) | (b & c)) + nt_buffer[6] + SQRT_2;
    d = (d << 5) | (d >> 27);
    c += ((d & (a | b)) | (a & b)) + nt_buffer[10] + SQRT_2;
    c = (c << 9) | (c >> 23);
    b += ((c & (d | a)) | (d & a)) + nt_buffer[14] + SQRT_2;
    b = (b << 13) | (b >> 19);

    a += ((b & (c | d)) | (c & d)) + nt_buffer[3] + SQRT_2;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += ((a & (b | c)) | (b & c)) + nt_buffer[7] + SQRT_2;
    d = (d << 5) | (d >> 27);
    c += ((d & (a | b)) | (a & b)) + nt_buffer[11] + SQRT_2;
    c = (c << 9) | (c >> 23);
    b += ((c & (d | a)) | (d & a)) + nt_buffer[15] + SQRT_2;
    b = (b << 13) | (b >> 19);

    /* Round 3 */
    a += (d ^ c ^ b) + nt_buffer[0] + SQRT_3;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ b ^ a) + nt_buffer[8] + SQRT_3;
    d = (d << 9) | (d >> 23);
    c += (b ^ a ^ d) + nt_buffer[4] + SQRT_3;
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ d ^ c) + nt_buffer[12] + SQRT_3;
    b = (b << 15) | (b >> 17);

    a += (d ^ c ^ b) + nt_buffer[2] + SQRT_3;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ b ^ a) + nt_buffer[10] + SQRT_3;
    d = (d << 9) | (d >> 23);
    c += (b ^ a ^ d) + nt_buffer[6] + SQRT_3;
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ d ^ c) + nt_buffer[14] + SQRT_3;
    b = (b << 15) | (b >> 17);

    a += (d ^ c ^ b) + nt_buffer[1] + SQRT_3;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ b ^ a) + nt_buffer[9] + SQRT_3;
    d = (d << 9) | (d >> 23);
    c += (b ^ a ^ d) + nt_buffer[5] + SQRT_3;
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ d ^ c) + nt_buffer[13] + SQRT_3;
    b = (b << 15) | (b >> 17);

    a += (d ^ c ^ b) + nt_buffer[3] + SQRT_3;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ b ^ a) + nt_buffer[11] + SQRT_3;
    d = (d << 9) | (d >> 23);
    c += (b ^ a ^ d) + nt_buffer[7] + SQRT_3;
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ d ^ c) + nt_buffer[15] + SQRT_3;
    b = (b << 15) | (b >> 17);

    output[0] = a + 0x67452301;
    output[1] = b + 0xefcdab89;
    output[2] = c + 0x98badcfe;
    output[3] = d + 0x10325476;

    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Convert the hash to hex (for being readable)
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        unsigned int n = output[i];

        //iterate the bytes of the integer
        for(; j<4; j++)
        {
            unsigned int convert = n % 256;
            hex_format[i * 8 + j * 2 + 1] = itoa16[convert % 16];
            convert = convert / 16;
            hex_format[i * 8 + j * 2 + 0] = itoa16[convert % 16];
            n = n / 256;
        }
    }       
}


int main()
{
    char* d_hex;
    char h_hex[33] = "";

    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc(&d_hex, 33 * sizeof(char)));

    NTBruteforce<<<1, 1>>>(d_hex);

    CUDA_CHECK_ERROR();

    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy(h_hex, d_hex, 32 * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)); 
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(d_hex));

    h_hex[32] = '\0';
    std::cout << h_hex << std::endl;
}
```

which always returns `35B5C3F393D57F7836FF61514BCF1289`. This was tested on Linux with CUDA 5.0, GeForce GT 650M and 319.12 beta drivers.

### Update

Here is the file I used to test with PyCUDA. Note that I had to modify a few things:

- Escape the 2 `\n` I added, else PyCUDA processes them...
- Add `no_extern_c=True` to `SourceModule` and put `NTBruteforce` in `extern "C"`, else compilation fails for me (`error: this declaration may not have extern "C" linkage`).

The complete PyCUDA program becomes:

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy
from passlib.hash import nthash

mod = SourceModule(
"""
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INIT_A 0x67452301
#define INIT_B 0xefcdab89
#define INIT_C 0x98badcfe
#define INIT_D 0x10325476

#define SQRT_2 0x5a827999
#define SQRT_3 0x6ed9eba1

#define CUDA_CHECK_ERROR()  __cuda_check_errors(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL(err) __cuda_safe_call(err, __FILE__, __LINE__)

inline void __cuda_check_errors(const char *filename, const int line_number)
{
    cudaError err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if(err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CUDA error %i at %s:%i: %s\\n",
               err, filename, line_number, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }
}

inline void __cuda_safe_call(cudaError err, const char *filename, const int line_number)
{
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CUDA error %i at %s:%i: %s\\n",
               err, filename, line_number, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }
}

__device__ void NTLM(char *, int, char*);
__device__ __constant__ char itoa16[17] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

extern "C" {

__global__ void NTBruteforce(char *hex_format){
    char test[4] = {'t', 'h', 'e', 'n'};
    NTLM(test, 4, hex_format);      
}

}

__device__ void NTLM(char *key, int key_length, char *hex_format) {
    unsigned int nt_buffer[16] = { 0 };
    unsigned int output[4] = { 0 };

    //Globals for rounds
    unsigned int a = INIT_A;
    unsigned int b = INIT_B;
    unsigned int c = INIT_C;
    unsigned int d = INIT_D;

    // Prepare the string for hash calculation
    int i;
    int length = key_length;

    for (i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
        nt_buffer[i] = key[2 * i] | (key[2 * i + 1] << 16);

    //padding
    if (length % 2 == 1)
        nt_buffer[i] = key[length - 1] | 0x800000;
    else
        nt_buffer[i] = 0x80;

    //put the length
    nt_buffer[14] = length << 4;

    // NTLM hash calculation

    /* Round 1 */
    a += (d ^ (b & (c ^ d))) + nt_buffer[0];
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ (a & (b ^ c))) + nt_buffer[1];
    d = (d << 7) | (d >> 25);
    c += (b ^ (d & (a ^ b))) + nt_buffer[2];
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ (c & (d ^ a))) + nt_buffer[3];
    b = (b << 19) | (b >> 13);

    a += (d ^ (b & (c ^ d))) + nt_buffer[4];
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ (a & (b ^ c))) + nt_buffer[5];
    d = (d << 7) | (d >> 25);
    c += (b ^ (d & (a ^ b))) + nt_buffer[6];
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ (c & (d ^ a))) + nt_buffer[7];
    b = (b << 19) | (b >> 13);

    a += (d ^ (b & (c ^ d))) + nt_buffer[8];
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ (a & (b ^ c))) + nt_buffer[9];
    d = (d << 7) | (d >> 25);
    c += (b ^ (d & (a ^ b))) + nt_buffer[10];
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ (c & (d ^ a))) + nt_buffer[11];
    b = (b << 19) | (b >> 13);

    a += (d ^ (b & (c ^ d))) + nt_buffer[12];
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ (a & (b ^ c))) + nt_buffer[13];
    d = (d << 7) | (d >> 25);
    c += (b ^ (d & (a ^ b))) + nt_buffer[14];
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ (c & (d ^ a))) + nt_buffer[15];
    b = (b << 19) | (b >> 13);

    /* Round 2 */
    a += ((b & (c | d)) | (c & d)) + nt_buffer[0] + SQRT_2;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += ((a & (b | c)) | (b & c)) + nt_buffer[4] + SQRT_2;
    d = (d << 5) | (d >> 27);
    c += ((d & (a | b)) | (a & b)) + nt_buffer[8] + SQRT_2;
    c = (c << 9) | (c >> 23);
    b += ((c & (d | a)) | (d & a)) + nt_buffer[12] + SQRT_2;
    b = (b << 13) | (b >> 19);

    a += ((b & (c | d)) | (c & d)) + nt_buffer[1] + SQRT_2;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += ((a & (b | c)) | (b & c)) + nt_buffer[5] + SQRT_2;
    d = (d << 5) | (d >> 27);
    c += ((d & (a | b)) | (a & b)) + nt_buffer[9] + SQRT_2;
    c = (c << 9) | (c >> 23);
    b += ((c & (d | a)) | (d & a)) + nt_buffer[13] + SQRT_2;
    b = (b << 13) | (b >> 19);

    a += ((b & (c | d)) | (c & d)) + nt_buffer[2] + SQRT_2;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += ((a & (b | c)) | (b & c)) + nt_buffer[6] + SQRT_2;
    d = (d << 5) | (d >> 27);
    c += ((d & (a | b)) | (a & b)) + nt_buffer[10] + SQRT_2;
    c = (c << 9) | (c >> 23);
    b += ((c & (d | a)) | (d & a)) + nt_buffer[14] + SQRT_2;
    b = (b << 13) | (b >> 19);

    a += ((b & (c | d)) | (c & d)) + nt_buffer[3] + SQRT_2;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += ((a & (b | c)) | (b & c)) + nt_buffer[7] + SQRT_2;
    d = (d << 5) | (d >> 27);
    c += ((d & (a | b)) | (a & b)) + nt_buffer[11] + SQRT_2;
    c = (c << 9) | (c >> 23);
    b += ((c & (d | a)) | (d & a)) + nt_buffer[15] + SQRT_2;
    b = (b << 13) | (b >> 19);

    /* Round 3 */
    a += (d ^ c ^ b) + nt_buffer[0] + SQRT_3;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ b ^ a) + nt_buffer[8] + SQRT_3;
    d = (d << 9) | (d >> 23);
    c += (b ^ a ^ d) + nt_buffer[4] + SQRT_3;
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ d ^ c) + nt_buffer[12] + SQRT_3;
    b = (b << 15) | (b >> 17);

    a += (d ^ c ^ b) + nt_buffer[2] + SQRT_3;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ b ^ a) + nt_buffer[10] + SQRT_3;
    d = (d << 9) | (d >> 23);
    c += (b ^ a ^ d) + nt_buffer[6] + SQRT_3;
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ d ^ c) + nt_buffer[14] + SQRT_3;
    b = (b << 15) | (b >> 17);

    a += (d ^ c ^ b) + nt_buffer[1] + SQRT_3;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ b ^ a) + nt_buffer[9] + SQRT_3;
    d = (d << 9) | (d >> 23);
    c += (b ^ a ^ d) + nt_buffer[5] + SQRT_3;
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ d ^ c) + nt_buffer[13] + SQRT_3;
    b = (b << 15) | (b >> 17);

    a += (d ^ c ^ b) + nt_buffer[3] + SQRT_3;
    a = (a << 3) | (a >> 29);
    d += (c ^ b ^ a) + nt_buffer[11] + SQRT_3;
    d = (d << 9) | (d >> 23);
    c += (b ^ a ^ d) + nt_buffer[7] + SQRT_3;
    c = (c << 11) | (c >> 21);
    b += (a ^ d ^ c) + nt_buffer[15] + SQRT_3;
    b = (b << 15) | (b >> 17);

    output[0] = a + 0x67452301;
    output[1] = b + 0xefcdab89;
    output[2] = c + 0x98badcfe;
    output[3] = d + 0x10325476;

    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Convert the hash to hex (for being readable)
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        unsigned int n = output[i];

        //iterate the bytes of the integer
        for(; j<4; j++)
        {
            unsigned int convert = n % 256;
            hex_format[i * 8 + j * 2 + 1] = itoa16[convert % 16];
            convert = convert / 16;
            hex_format[i * 8 + j * 2 + 0] = itoa16[convert % 16];
            n = n / 256;
        }
    }       
}
""", no_extern_c=True)
expected = nthash.encrypt('then')
data = numpy.array(expected)
cleartext = numpy.zeros_like(data)
cleartext_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(data.nbytes)
func = mod.get_function('NTBruteforce')
func(cleartext_gpu, block=(1,1,1))
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(cleartext, cleartext_gpu)
print 'Expected: {}'.format(expected.upper())
print "GPU     : {}".format(cleartext.tostring())
```

The result is, as expected:

```
Expected: 35B5C3F393D57F7836FF61514BCF1289
GPU     : 35B5C3F393D57F7836FF61514BCF1289
```

Comment: edit: yea I tried both the C++ standalone and the updated PyCUDA both give me 2/10 wrong results. The strange thing is I compiled the C++ standalone once and upon consecutive executions it gives different results sometimes
thnx for the update! But it still doesn't work always. i copy/pasted your code straight insto Sublime-text. Is there any chance the problem is faulty hardware / drivers / operating system? Right now I just wanna know what the possible problem could be...;S

Comment: @s3n5e1: it can always be many things. The first thing is the code itself, obviously. Then, to test for faulty hardware, you'd have to test with some other program (maybe this [test suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cudagpumemtest/) if you were on Linux, something else for Windows). As for the drivers and the CUDA version, it is usually advisable to get the latest, else you will not get all the bug fixes. Alas sometimes new versions also bring their share of bugs. Note that with CUDA, new versions can mean changes in the API. For the OS part, I doubt it has anything to do with it.